Using r to load SQL file with french column select
I'm using sqlcmd in SQL Server to, create a action to move data from one structure to a other predefined database table. where both have the same collation
Where I have some French column names. like: [numéro de la], if I do a select in the execute file I get the result I want. But if I use the same SQL in the referred file, using ":r" it will die, with a

Invalid column name 'num�ro de la'.

execute.sql:
:setvar SrcDB [xxxx]
:setvar prefix [xxx]
:setvar StaDB [xx]
use $(StaDB)

select top 1 e.[numéro de la] FROM $(SrcDB).$(prefix).documents e
    
-- Common parameters
:setvar Path "C:\file path\"
:r $(Path)conv_xxx.sql

conv_xxx.sql
print 'test'
select top 1 e.[numéro de la] FROM $(SrcDB).$(prefix).documents e

When it is run, it will show the result from the first select in the execute.exe file, and print the 'test' message. And then show the error

Invalid column name 'num�ro de la'.

Note, if I run conv_xxx.sql, with the set var in the file, it just works.
I have been looking on google, but can't find anything on, how it make it load a file with the right format.
I'm on a danish pc, so I think the problem is, when the ":r" action is getting the file, and reading it. it will do it in the wrong format. so once it loaded it get a � instead of é.
One fix, that would work, is to just make a function to replace/remove the é direct from the column name.
Is there a way to force encoding of file?
Recap of problem:
":r" loads file with � instead of é

What version is reported by sqlcmd -?? If you're using version 17.5.1.1 or later on Linux/macOS then you should be able to use the -f switch to specify encodings, e.g.: -f 65001 for reading and writing UTF-8 encoded files. It's not clear when that option got added to the Windows version, but probably around the same time.

SQLCMD Mode, in SSMS, doesn't have an option specifying the code page, if I recall correctly, @AlwaysLearning .

And yet nowhere does the op mention SSMS.
